# How to get category discription?

Tags: magento2

This is phtml code for getting selected category. I want to get category description. How can I get that?

```php
<?php
    $catId =2;
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);           
    $subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<ul>
    <li> <span> All Categories </span> </li>
        <?php
            foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
               if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                   $subcat_url = $subcat->getUrl();
                   $subcat_img = "";
                   $placeholder_img = "/media/placeholder.png";
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $subcat_url; ?>">
                <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Category Description, you have to load Category and after that, you can use **getDescription()** function.

I have made some changes in your code. Please find the new code here:

```php
    <?php
        $catId =2;
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);           
        $subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li> <span> All Categories </span> </li>
            <?php
                foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {

                   if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                       $subcat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());   
                       $subcat_url = $subcat->getUrl();
                       $subcat_img = "";
                       $placeholder_img = "/media/placeholder.png";
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $subcat_url; ?>">
                    <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                </a>
                <p><?php echo $subcat->getDescription(); ?></p>
            </li>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
```

**Note: In Magento 2, the direct use of ObjectManager in template files is not a good practice. Dependency injection is the recommended approach.**

For more details on how to use ObjectManager and what the consequences are of using the ObjectManager directly, you can follow the link below:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Comment: i am newbie in magento, i don't know about ObjectManager